# Is there a way to ensure that the decision variables created by mathematical program are not of type AutoDiffXd?

Tags: drake

I'm trying to set the position of a model in my plant to a state vector, q,  generated by my mathematical program as a decision variable in order to test whether that state is valid (checking whether the model is in a valid location with a distance query).

This, to my understanding, requires converting the diagram to which the plant and scene graph are connected to the appropriate types based on q's type (To autodiff or float depending on q, then to float for distance query if the diagram was converted to autodiff).

Converting the diagram to autodiff in the event that q is of type autodiff is fine, but converting it to float (in order for query_object.ComputeSignedDistanceQuery to work) produces this error:

> RuntimeError: System ::_ of type drake::systems::Diagramdrake::AutoDiffXd does not support scalar conversion to type double (because System ::_::scene_graph of type drake::geometry::SceneGraphdrake::AutoDiffXd does not support scalar conversion to type double)

The problem then being that a AutoDiff typed scene graph cannot be converted to float.

The 'easiest' solution to this I can think of is to prevent having to convert to AutoDiff by somehow enforcing that the state vectors generated by mathematical program cannot be of type AutoDiff. Is this possible?

If not, is there then some other way of avoiding converting scene graph to autodiff (considering that only plant needs to be converted for set_position)?

---

Using extract value with a slice (q[1, :]) of the decision variable matrix (with q.dtype == AutoDiffXd evaluating to true) yields the following TypeError:

> TypeError: ExtractValue(): incompatible function arguments. The
> following argument types are supported:
> 1. (auto_diff_matrix: numpy.ndarray[object[m, n]]) -> numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[m, n]]
>
> Invoked with: array([Variable('q(1,0)', Continuous),
> Variable('q(1,1)', Continuous),
> Variable('q(1,2)', Continuous), Variable('q(1,3)', Continuous),
> Variable('q(1,4)', Continuous), Variable('q(1,5)', Continuous),
> Variable('q(1,6)', Continuous), Variable('q(1,7)', Continuous),
> Variable('q(1,8)', Continuous), Variable('q(1,9)', Continuous),
> Variable('q(1,10)', Continuous), Variable('q(1,11)', Continuous),
> Variable('q(1,12)', Continuous), Variable('q(1,13)', Continuous),
> Variable('q(1,14)', Continuous), Variable('q(1,15)', Continuous),
> Variable('q(1,16)', Continuous), Variable('q(1,17)', Continuous),
> Variable('q(1,18)', Continuous), Variable('q(1,19)', Continuous),
> Variable('q(1,20)', Continuous)], dtype=object)

Answer (score 0):

I probably need to understand more details from your setup to help.  Decision variables in `MathematicalProgram` are always symbolic (not autodiff).  But generic constraints can get called with either double or autodiff values. [This tutorial](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Drake-0b3b2c53-a7ad-441b-80f8-bf8350752305/project/Tutorials-2b4fc509-aef2-417d-a40d-6071dfed9199/notebook/mathematical_program_multibody_plant-df29773c52694b849da5c7bc73a2a888) is very relevant.

If you do have an autodiff matrix and want to convert it to double, you can use [ExtractValue](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.autodiffutils.html?highlight=extractvalue#pydrake.autodiffutils.ExtractValue).

Comment: This looks like what I need! Except using it with what I believe to be a AutoDiff typed numpy array yields a TypeError... Is there a trick to this? I've added the details to the question

Comment: Update: figured out that I need to do this within my constraint, but then I run into the problem of needing to output an autodiff value with my constraint (currently returns a float).

Comment: If the value you return from the constraint is a bunch of standard arithmetic on the inputs, then I would expect it to stay of type AutoDiffXd.  It seems suspicious that you would have a float coming out.

Comment: The output of my constraint function is a vector containing the results of the signed distance queries done on a float typed Query object

Comment: ok.  so there are two issues.  Probably you are using a query object produced by a SceneGraph<double> in your method, despite the variables being passed being an autodiff type.  Probably you need to create the query object using the autodiffs inside the method.  When you do that properly, you might be limited by the relatively limited AutoDiff support in SceneGraph.  You can see the support table here: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_query_object.html#a0918d61334404a7680145cb882a18d52

But requests and contributions are welcome.